# How to prove that $\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} +\frac{c}{a+b} +\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \ge \frac{5}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers. Then

$$\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} +\frac{c}{a+b} +\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \ge \frac{5}{2}$$

How would you prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):
$$ \left(\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} +\frac{c}{a+b}\right) \Big(a(b+c)+b(a+c)+c(a+b)\Big) \ge (a+b+c)^2$$
Then 
$$ \operatorname{LHS} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(ab+bc+ca)} +\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}} = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2(ab+bc+ca)} +1 +\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}} $$
Let $\ \xi = \displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}}$. Then $\xi \ge 1$, since 
$$0\le (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 = 2\left( a^2+b^2+c^2 -ab-bc-ca \right)$$
Now $ \operatorname{LHS} \ge \dfrac{\xi^2}{2} + 1 + \dfrac{1}{\xi}$.
We notice that
$$ 2 \left(\frac{\xi^2}{2} + 1 + \frac{1}{\xi}\right) - 5= \xi^2 + \frac{2}{\xi} - 3 = \frac{(\xi-1)^2 (\xi+2)}{\xi} \ge 0  $$
Hence,
$$ \operatorname{LHS} \ge \frac{\xi^2}{2} + 1 + \frac{1}{\xi} \ge \frac{5}{2} $$